# nc host.docker.internal is not working inside a container to access the host IP address

Tags: docker, docker-machine, netcat

I have started my **nc utility** inside a container named "**ain_container**" and exposed two proxies to outside as shown below with the ubuntu 14.04 image.

[image]

Then I started the nc utility with two ports as shown below

[image]

Now I Have created two more containers with ubuntu 14.04 image and trying to access and listen in these two containers.

I'm trying to connect to host IP with **host.docker.internal** but somehow its giving an error.

[image]

Comment: `host.docker.internal` is only supported under MacOS and Windows. On what platform are you running Docker?

Comment: Running on ubuntu 16.04